# pytest doesn't output inner assertion differences

Tags: python, pytest

I've noticed pytest swallows/doesn't output inner assertion differences. I have some library code that includes its own assertions, i.e.:

> ```
>   assert d['key_a'] == d['key_b']
> ```

The tests I'm running are using this library, and apparently there's a failure:

> ```
>   assert d['key_a'] == d['key_b']
>   E       AssertionError
> ```

Is there a way to show the difference? i.e when called directly from the test module:

> ```
>   a = {'f': 10, 'g': 11}
>   assert a['f'] == a['g']
>   E       assert 10 == 11
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pytest.register_assert_rewrite` (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html?highlight=pytest.register_assert_rewrite#pytest.register_assert_rewrite) does the trick.